# Why does xcom_pull from EmrCreateJobFlowOperator returns None in Airflow

Tags: python, airflow, amazon-emr

Here's my Dag:
I am trying to spin an EMR cluster and trying to use its cluster id in adding steps.
Use case is : Want to spin a cluster and save its cluster id somewhere in s3.
But the xcom_pull is showing error.

```
from datetime import timedelta
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.contrib.operators.emr_add_steps_operator import EmrAddStepsOperator
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.emr_create_job_flow import EmrCreateJobFlowOperator
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.sensors.emr_job_flow import EmrJobFlowSensor
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago

SPARK_STEPS = [
    {
        'Name': 'emr_spin',
        'ActionOnFailure': 'CONTINUE',
        'HadoopJarStep': {
            'Jar': 'command-runner.jar',
            'Args': ['/usr/lib/spark/bin/run-example', 'SparkPi', '10'],
        },
    }
]

JOB_FLOW_OVERRIDES = {
    'Name': 'airflow_trial',
    'ReleaseLabel': 'emr-5.29.0',
    'Applications': [{'Name': 'Spark'}],
    'Instances': {
        'InstanceGroups': [
            {
                'Name': "Master",
                'Market': 'ON_DEMAND',
                'InstanceRole': 'MASTER',
                'InstanceType': 'm5.xlarge',
                'InstanceCount': 1,
            }
        ],
        'KeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps': False,
        'TerminationProtected': False,
    },
    'Steps': [],
    'JobFlowRole': 'EMR_EC2_DefaultRole',
    'ServiceRole': 'EMR_DefaultRole',
}

with DAG(
    dag_id='xcom',
    default_args={
        'owner': 'airflow'
    },
    dagrun_timeout=timedelta(hours=2),
    start_date=days_ago(2),
    schedule_interval='0 3 * * *',
    tags=['example'],
) as dag:

    # [START howto_operator_emr_automatic_steps_tasks]
    job_flow_creator = EmrCreateJobFlowOperator(
        task_id='create_job_flow',
        job_flow_overrides=JOB_FLOW_OVERRIDES,
        aws_conn_id='aws_default',
        emr_conn_id='emr_default',
    )

    step_adder = EmrAddStepsOperator(
        task_id='add_steps',
        job_flow_id = "{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='create_job_flow', key='return_value') }}",
        aws_conn_id='aws_default',
        steps=SPARK_STEPS,
    )
```

Output:
XCom

```
Key         Value
job_flow_id None
```

Please help.
I want to save the cluster id in json.
But I'm not getting it using xcom

Comment: Did EmrCreateJobFlowOperator finished successfuly?

Comment: Yes. It did finished successfully. But the steps were not added through EmrAddStepsOperator.

Comment: From where are you print job_flow_id, please share that code

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to pass the `job_flow_id`, can you please try them and let me know the outcome.

first, with `xcom`, try using xcom_pull simply as below

```
step_adder = EmrAddStepsOperator(
    task_id='add_steps',
    job_flow_id="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull('create_job_flow', key='return_value') }}",
    aws_conn_id='aws_default',
    steps=SPARK_STEPS,
)
```

with `output` key of the EmrCreateJobFlowOperator

```
step_adder = EmrAddStepsOperator(
    task_id='add_steps',
    job_flow_id=job_flow_creator.output,
    aws_conn_id='aws_default',
    steps=SPARK_STEPS,
)
```

not sure but also try `job_flow_creator` alone, without `job_flow_creator.output`

Comment: When I'm using job_flow_creator.output it is working fine. But when I'm using job_flow_id="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull('create_job_flow', key='return_value') }}", the steps are not getting added.
Also when I'm trying to store either : job_flow_creator.output  or "{{ task_instance.xcom_pull('create_job_flow', key='return_value') }}"  in a string it stores nothing 
But ideally it should store the cluster id

Comment: ob_flow_creator.output adds the steps as well? Do you need `job_flow_id="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull('create_job_flow', key='return_value') }}` specially?

Comment: Feel free to upvote/accept the answer if it helped :)

Comment: I need to use job_flow_id="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull('create_job_flow', key='return_value') }} for capturing the cluster id specifically in a string to that I can save it somewhere in S3 for other step addition in the same cluster.

Comment: job_flow_creator.output provides you with the cluster_id (job_flow_id == cluster_id), you can save it, pass it to the operator and even persist it to s3. let me know if I am missing something?

Comment: Tried saving the id using job_flow_creator.output but it didnt worked.
It saved {{ task_instance.xcom_pull('create_job_flow', key='return_value') }} .
I'm not sure how should I exactly use job_flow_creator.output to push the cluster id in S3.